NGINX reverse proxy stripping port
I have a web service, running on :3000, behind NGINX, that runs on :46606
When requested, a single resource fails with:
Unable to preload CSS for http://SOME.IP.ADDRESS/theme.css?v=undefined

If I shut-down NGINX and configure my web service to be directly exposed (listen on :46606) - the HTTP response is 200 and the URL is correct:
http://SOME.IP.ADDRESS:46606/theme.css?v=undefined

Here is my NGINX config:
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;

events {
        worker_connections 768;
        # multi_accept on;
}

http {

        ##
        # Basic Settings
        ##

        sendfile on;
        tcp_nopush on;
        types_hash_max_size 2048;
        # server_tokens off;

        # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
        # server_name_in_redirect off;

        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
        default_type application/octet-stream;

        ##
        # SSL Settings
        ##

        ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

        ##
        # Logging Settings
        ##

        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

        ##
        # Gzip Settings
        ##

        gzip on;

        # gzip_vary on;
        # gzip_proxied any;
        # gzip_comp_level 6;
        # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
        # gzip_http_version 1.1;
        # gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

        ##
        # Virtual Host Configs
        ##

        include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
        include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}

Here is my NGINX vhost config:
server {
        listen 46606 ;
        listen [::]:46606 ;

        location / {
                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;
                proxy_buffering off;
                        #proxy_redirect off;
                        proxy_http_version 1.1;
                        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
                        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
                        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
                        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        }
    }

I talked with ChatGPT, Googled, Stackoverflow/Serverfault checked.
Tried swithing:
proxy_set_header Host $host
to
proxy_set_header Host $http_host
I also tried some other options for the / location in the NGINX vhost, but with no luck so far.
Seems the problem is in my NGINX configuration, but I am unable to figure out what is wrong, since directly-exposed app works properly...
Many thanks to anyone, sharing my pain!
